# Como faço para gerar um arquivo excel com os dados do google drive que apareça só o ID do link?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando fazer um arquivo xlsx que tem um link especifico do google drive, e nesse link tem mais de 25 mil arquivos, com isso eu queria que o programa, lesse todos e me retornasse todos os links e seus respectivos ids para consegui fazer um download direto, ainda estou apredendo, e meu amigo me pediu ajuda para isso e eu quero ajuda-lo, alguém poderia me ajudar. Desculpe eu não tenho nada do codigo ainda to iniciando agora. Nem sei se tem como fazer tal coisa, mas espero que me ajudem

Comment: Você já fez essa pergunta e ela já foi fechada. Importante seguir [as orientações já dadas lá](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/571649/existe-algum-comando-que-consiga-fazer-isso-para-me-ajudar#comment1005159_571649), editando aquela postagem conforme os links passados. Para evitar descentralização de informações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas na postagem linkada continua disponível.